# Create new array from partial one

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

I have a data.frame `dat` which has two columns of numbers. I would like to create a new array that has the values of the second column of the data.frame in those positions that match the numbers in the first column and -99 otherwise. In essence, I have:

```
dat
   col1 col2
1     2    6
2     5    43
3     10   67
```

and I would like to create a new array of length 10 (the highest value present in `col1`) that would look like this:

```
-99, 6, -99, -99, 43, -99, -99, -99, -99, 67
```

In my data.frame `dat` I have several hundred thousand rows and my final array will also be several hundred thousand long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
> result <- rep(-99,max(dat$col1))
> result[dat$col1] <- dat$col2
> result
 [1] -99   6 -99 -99  43 -99 -99 -99 -99  67
```